# Yii2: What is the relation name?

Tags: php, yii2, relational-database

For the ActiveRecord, what is "the name of the relation" that is to be used in eg. [`link()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#link()-detail) and [`unlink()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#unlink()-detail) - where is that defined?

**UPDATE:**
The documentation now includes an example - though it doesn't show exactly how the camel case name is converted - as the answer to this question does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have got relation set like:

```
public function getRelationName()
```

Relation name is `relationName`.